# how can I unsecure xampp in ubuntu?

Tags: xampp, localhost

when I access my IP in some other computer it requires username and password , I want no such type of security I want direct access to my xampp, phpmyadmin directory in any computer in same network. I've attached some snapshots :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you found any solution/

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .htaccess file in the htdocs folder. May be that is making your directory password protected.